# Python datetime.datetime from time.structtime difference

Tags: python, timestamp, python-datetime

I use feedparser to grab the entries from some RSS feeds.
The entries have a published_parsed field which are parsed by feedparser into time.structtime.

I use this function to convert the time.structtime into a datetime.datetime:

```
def publishParsedToDatetime(structTime): 
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(structTime))
```

Input (structtime):

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=2015, tm_mon=8, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=20, tm_min=28, tm_sec=33, tm_wday=5, tm_yday=213, tm_isdst=0)
```

Output (datetime):

```
2015-08-01 21:28:33
```

I see a problem which could be timezone related, there is **1 hour difference** between the structtime and the datetime values.

The structtime value is UTC.
But the datetime.datetime value is neither UTC, nor my current timezone (CET, Central European Time, we observe Summertime, so we have UTC + 2hrs at the moment).

How can this be explained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, as explained in the [documentation for `datetime.fromtimestamp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp), it converts to local time by default:

> Return the local date and time corresponding to the POSIX timestamp, such as is returned by time.time(). If optional argument tz is None or not specified, the timestamp is converted to the platform’s local date and time, and the returned datetime object is naive

The 1 hour difference can then be explained by the [field `tm_isdst=0`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.struct_time) tells it to not use daylight savings (despite your local time zone using it).

To see this more clearly, we construct two test cases

```py
import time, datetime

# this is how your time object was constructed before
tm_isdst = 0
t = time.mktime((2015, 8, 1, 20, 28, 33, 5, 213, tm_isdst))
print("Old conversion: {0}".format(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t)))

# this is what happens if you let mktime "divine" a time zone
tm_isdst = -1
t = time.mktime((2015, 8, 1, 20, 28, 33, 5, 213, tm_isdst))
print("New conversion: {0}".format(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t)))
```

The output of this is as follows:

```
Old conversion: 2015-08-01 21:28:33
New conversion: 2015-08-01 20:28:33
```

The problem then, you see, is that the `structTime` object being passed to your `publishParsedToDatetime` has `tm_isdst=0` but the time stamp you wanted to parse was for a DST time zone.

As you have already noted in another comment, the proper solution to this is probably to always use UTC in your back-end code, and only do time zone handling when showing the time to the user, or when reading user input.

Comment: How can adjust it to local time?

Comment: You need to tell the fromtimestamp function which time zone to use, see the documentation I linked to (it is very good).

Comment: OK, how do I specify CET as the optional argument of .fromtimestamp?

Comment: Hi, sorry I took so long to reply, I was asleep. I'll update my answer to include a more thorough explanation.

Comment: No problem, I have fixed the issue in a way I am testing now. So all's fine.

Answer (score 1):

[`calendar.timegm`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.timegm) takes a *UTC* timetuple as input and returns its timestamp.
In contrast, [`time.mktime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.mktime) takes a *local* timetuple as input and returns its (UTC) timestamp. All timestamps represent seconds since the Epoch, 1970-1-1 00:00:00 UTC.

[`utcfromtimestamp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp) takes a timestamp as input and converts it to a naive
(i.e. timezone-unaware) UTC datetime.
[`fromtimestamp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp) takes the same timestamp and converts it to the corresponding
naive local datetime.

Since your timetuples (e.g. `structTime`) are UTC timetuples, you should use `calendar.timegm`, not `time.mktime`, to find the correct timestamp.
Once you have the correct timestamp, `fromtimestamp` will return the corresponding naive local datetime.

---

```
import time
import calendar
import datetime as DT
timetuple = (2015, 8, 1, 20, 28, 33, 5, 213, 0)
timestamp = calendar.timegm(timetuple)    
naive_local_date = DT.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)    
print('Naive local: {}'.format(naive_local_date))
```

yields

```
Naive local: 2015-08-01 22:28:33
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I decided to end this 'datetime hell' and store all dates and times in UTC only in my code. Local time conversion will only appear in the client code. My trouble with fromtimestamp arises from the fact that it does convert to local time, but ignores DST.